# Localization in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: localization, microsoft-metro

As far as I understand it Windows 8 uses a new type of resource file (*.resw). The trouble is, if I have, say, 2 different client applications (ASP.NET MVC and Metro) that share the same localization strings I'm now faced with 2 different resource files with basically identical content. Is there any way around that? Ideally, I'd have just one resource file for both clients, even if that means I'd have to move it to an assembly of its own.

Comment: have you tried to simply add the old resx file as a resource in metro solution? I can't check right now, but that could work.. I'll check this later

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share resources between different projects you should probably try to share the sources of the resources, not what the resources are compiled to for a particular platform.